# How to decode String to a corresponding Map?

Tags: java

I am new to Java. I have a problem that, I need to Implement the `decode(String)` method that decodes a String to a corresponding `Map`. In the assignment, the requirements are like this,

1. Empty keys and values are allowed, but the equals sign must be present (e.g. "=value", "key=").
2. If the key or value is empty, empty String should be returned.
3. If the given String is empty, an empty Map should be returned.
4. If the given String is null, null should be returned.

`Sample Input: one=1&two=2`
`Should return a Map containing {"one": "1", "two": "2"}`

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put("One", "1");
map.put("Two", "2");
map.put("", "");
map.put("Key", "");
map.put("", "Value");

Set<String> keys = map.keySet();

for(String key : keys) {
    System.out.print("\"" + key + "\""  + ":" + "\"" + map.get(key) + "\"");
}
```

My piece of code is giving output as required, But I have implemented this in the main method with `Map<K, V>` interface, while I need to write code that takes `String` as a parameter and decodes to Map.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried something yourself first?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with `map.put("Key", "");` and
`map.put("", "Value");`?

Comment: Read the assignment requirements 1 and 2. It's under the requirement.

Comment: @QBrute I do not where to start and how to write this particular code, as I am new to Java.

Comment: The best starting place will be splitting the string passed into decode() around the separator, i.e. 'String[] lines = String.split("&")'. You can then do validation on each of the lines to match your requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be:

```
public Map<String, String> parseMap(String mapString) {
  if (mapString == null || mapString.isEmpty()) {
    return Collections.emptyMap();
  }
  return Arrays.stream(mapString.split("&"))
    .map(this::splitParam)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue));
}

public AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String> splitParam(String it) {
  final int idx = it.indexOf("=");
  final String key = it.substring(0, idx);
  final String value = it.substring(idx + 1);
  return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(key, value);
}
```

usage

```
String inputString = "one=1&two=2";
Map<String, String> map = parseMap(inputString);

//your code to print the map again
Set<String> keys = map.keySet();

for(String key : keys) {
  System.out.print("\"" + key + "\""  + ":" + "\"" + map.get(key) + "\"");
}
```

Comment: it's working. Little thing to notice. `parseMap` is not a static method so we need to a created instance of the same class in order to call the method. Apart from that code is working fine. Thanks.

Comment: added the static keyword ;). One note: having empty keys is a weird requirement. If you have multiple empty keys the value will be overwritten and only the last will be included in the map.

Comment: Maybe its weird requirement, but its interview question from one company. Could not do anything about that.  It's nice that you have added `static` keyword, but when we use `this::splitQueryParameter`. It says `this cannot be referenced from a static context `. So I simply made that method non-static and things are good to go.

Comment: yeah, i also reverted it ^^

Answer (score 1):

try this in your editor, just 4 lines :)

```java
        String input = "one=1&two=2";
        String[] kvs = input.split("&");
        Map<String, String> hashMap = Stream.of(kvs)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(item -> item.split("=")[0], 
                         item -> item.split("=")[1]));
        hashMap.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ":" + v));
```